# Controlling scalp hair for braid effects?

Tags: particles

I'm trying to control hair particles to emulate scalp effects similar to French, Dutch or cornrow braids. The scalp patterning is important for several character designs.

Here's an example of the tight-to-scalp braiding I'm trying to achieve, sketched in grease pencil -- the two dutch braids on the sides of the head.

[image: head with grease pencil braiding sketched in]

I figure I could attempt a lot of curve guides for individual locks, but would that be efficient?

Any ideas?